# Download a full page with scrapy - not working with specifik url paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to download the content of https://en.wikinews.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Politics_and_conflicts&from=F

I can download it from other pages such as https://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Category:Politics_and_conflicts

I am new to scrapy and can't see why I can't use the first link. Below is my code:

```
import scrapy
import string
from urllib.parse import urljoin

class Test4Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test4"

    start_urls = [
        "https://en.wikinews.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Politics_and_conflicts&from=F",
        # "https://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Category:Politics_and_conflicts",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = "outfile.html"
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Below is the terminal output when using the first link that does not work

```
[daniel@C940-Manjaro DS_5]$ scrapy crawl test4
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.0.1 started (bot: DS_5)
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 15:48:22) - [GCC 7.3.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020), cryptography 2.8, Platform Linux-5.4.28-1-MANJARO-x86_64-with-arch-Manjaro-Linux
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'DS_5',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'DS_5.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['DS_5.spiders']}
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 3ce30513a5d7ab4e
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikinews.org/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://en.wikinews.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Politics_and_conflicts&from=F>
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 225,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 5176,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.340545,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 2, 17, 32, 19, 856792),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 55091200,
 'memusage/startup': 55091200,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/forbidden': 1,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 2, 17, 32, 19, 516247)}
2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
[daniel@C940-Manjaro DS_5]$
```

My overall goal is to scrape content from all articles with a given starting letter and I think that my code for that should be somewhat ready. It just seems I can't use it because I can't scrape some of the pages on https://en.wikinews.org

If there is anything I should change or provide to make answering easier please let me know and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For others having this problem the solution is:

Notice the line "2020-04-02 19:32:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: https://en.wikinews.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Politics_and_conflicts&from=F>"  (Links to an external site.)in your error output. You need to stop obeying the robots.txt.

In your settings.py, do:

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False
```

Comment: For others scraping Wikimedia sites, please don’t; they provide an API and data dumps that you can use to access all the data without overloading their servers.